# Access violation trying to change Android device R/W permission with Delphi

Tags: java, android, delphi, permissions

I'm using the excellent [Com port for Android](http://www.winsoft.sk/acomport.htm) to communicate using a serial connection between a [UOODO Android board](http://www.udoo.org/) and a hardware device. My serial port as seen from the Delphi App is "/dev/ttymxc3".

When I run my app, it tells me that 'permission is denied'. From console access on another port if I execute the command

```
chmod 666 /dev/ttymxc3
```

and then run my app again, it works ok.
So, I've tried to execute this command from within my app as follows based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857021/delphi-xe5-exec-root-command-conversion) and the "java.lang.Runtime" and "android.os.process"  import from [here on GitHub](https://github.com/FMXExpress/android-object-pascal-wrapper/)

```
uses
  java.lang.Runtime,
  Androidapi.Helpers;


    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
       TJRuntime.JavaClass.getRuntime.exec(StringToJString('chmod 666 /dev/ttymxc3'));
    end;
```

where pressing the button I hoped to change the permission from code. I get an access violation though. As suggested in the comments, to find out where this is coming from (and because the Delphi debugger does not work with this device) I executed the following:

```
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  RunTime : JRuntime;
  S : JString;
begin
   try
     RunTime := TJRuntime.JavaClass.getRuntime;
     if not Assigned( RunTime ) then
       begin
         ShowMessage( 'E1' );
         Exit;
       end;
   except
     on E:Exception do
       ShowMessageFmt( 'E1A:%s', [E.Message] );
   end;

   try
     S := StringToJString('chmod 666 /dev/ttymxc3');
     if not Assigned( S ) then
       begin
         ShowMessage( 'E2' );
         Exit;
       end;
   except
     on E:Exception do
       ShowMessageFmt( 'E2A:%s', [E.Message] );
   end;

   try
     RunTime.exec( S );
   except
     on E:Exception do
       ShowMessageFmt( 'E3A:%s', [E.Message] );
   end;
end;
```

The AV is shown to trigger my 'E3A' error, i.e use of 'exec'. My questions are: Why would I get this AV? Is what I'm doing fatally flawed? I.e should I even be able to set permissions on this device node from within a plain Delphi app? If so, can I change my app permissions to permit this?

Comment: OK, obvious question first: Have you traced into it with the debugger to verify that it's actually erroring on the call to `exec` and not something else?

Comment: @Mason: Good point. It's not helped by the fact that the board executes Delphi apps but doesn't support the debugger - I don't know why and others are having the same issues with certain Android devices. I also hoped that my mistake was so glaring to someone that this would suffice. However, good idea - I'll break down the calls with some messages and report my findings.

Comment: Yeah.  When working with strange and unexpected bugs, consciously asking really obvious questions like that is surprisingly effective at helping to resolve the issues.

Comment: I would assume that the console access is running as root, but your ordinary application is not. You cannot run chmod to grant yourself permissions that you don't already have; you can only grant access to others (assuming you're already the file's owner). So, does your application already own the file, and you want to grant access to others? Or has the OS created this file for you, and your application doesn't have the permission it needs to use it? Can you run *other* commands besides chmod?

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for your comment. As you say, I wondered if this was even possible. 'dev/ttymxc3' is actually a serial port, and there do seem to be people who say this sort of thing works. As another solution, can I bump my app permisions somehow? I 'own' the board and my app will be in charge of everything, so architecture-wise this is not a problem.

Answer (score -1):

i use nanopi2 with c++ builder rx10 seatel and booted android lolipop and winSoft comport component same as you
i had same problem in c++ builder when i used your method(access violation)
but i use another method to solve my problem that i suggest to use that
i think it solves your problem

in delphi

```
uses
  Posix.Stdlib


_system('su -c chmod 777 dev/ttyAMA0') ;
```

in c++ builder

```
#include <Posix.Stdlib.hpp>

system('su -c chmod 777 dev/ttyAMA0') ;

my serial port in nanopi2 is ttyAMA0

carefull for sucssesfully open port  i had to set SELINUX to permission mode    by 
this instruction

 _system('su -c setenforce 0');
```

http://www.fmxexpress.com/launch-a-url-or-document-on-ios-and-android-with-delphi-firemonkey/

i love embarcadero 
i love c++ builder

Comment: Please, format your code using markdown. For more information [Formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)